# MAC command git-tf not Found

Tags: xcode, macos, git, azure-devops, git-tf

**Hello all.**
I search a lot but nothing really help.
I'm using xcode 5 to develop IOS app, with Team Foundation Server 2013 via git repository. For the first 2 projects all was fine with git-tf commands series. But after that it gives me git-tf command not found ,it's somehow weird to stop working suddenly. 
Any help will be appreciated

> -bash: git-tf: command not found

Comment: Your question is unspecific - a missing command is very often caused by any os-changes, like updates, installations and so on. I don't know how to provide any help based on the information you may post here.

Comment: thx bro I was missing make changes to global variable

Answer (score 0):

You might search for any `git-tf` contents in your filesystem using:

```
sudo find / -name git-tf
```

Prepend `sudo` to avoid warnings about unsearchable folders. If `git-tf` can't be found you may decide to reinstall it, following the instructions on the [project-page](https://gittf.codeplex.com/).

Otherwise you should check your `$PATH`-variable - as mentioned on the git-tf-instructions.

Comment: Thanks bro it seems work well today. Hope Apple release soon direct integration For TFS servers